# Get everything between start and end word

Tags: python, regex

Look at this:

```
set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit

set policy id 1508

exit

set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit

set policy id 1507

set service "TCP-37"

exit
```

I want to set the whole lines before exit into the Python list which meaning :

```
    list=[
'set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit\n\nset policy id 1508',
'set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit\n\nset policy id 1507\n\nset service "TCP-37"'
]
```

How can I do this using regex?

note that i want the whole codes before exit in one of the list indexes. i mean :

```
    list=[
'set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit\n\nset policy id 1508',
'set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit\n\nset policy id 1507\n\nset service "TCP-37"'
]
```

not this :

```
list=[
'set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit',
'set policy id 1508',
'set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit',
'set policy id 1507',
'set service "TCP-37"'
]
```

i want the

```
re.findall()
```

pattern for finding the string which is started by set and ended by exit.

tanks.

Comment: Just a random question. Do you "need" a regex solution to this or will any solution do?

Comment: my knowledge in regex is really low. so i prefer the regex solution. in fact there is basic problems in regex for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below code also which uses a negative lookahead and a (DOTALL modifier),

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit
... 
... set policy id 1508
... 
... exit
... 
... set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit
... 
... set policy id 1507
... 
... set service "TCP-37"
... 
... exit"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'set(?:(?!exit).)*', s, re.DOTALL)
>>> m
['set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit\n\nset policy id 1508\n\n', 'set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit\n\nset policy id 1507\n\nset service "TCP-37"\n\n']
```

Comment: this is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider that the text is in a variable called text. You can use the split method of the str class ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split ).
In a Python interpreter:

```
>>> t = """set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit
...
... set policy id 1508
...
... exit
...
... set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit
...
... set policy id 1507
...
... set service "TCP-37"
...
... exit"""
>>> t.split("exit")
['set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit\n\nset policy id 1508\n\n', '\n\nset policy id 1507 from "C
MS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit\n\nset policy id 1507\n\nset service "TCP-37"\n\n', '']
```

If you want to avoid the last empty element in the list, you can call the split method with "exit\n".
You can also call the strip method on each item of the list to remove whitespaces at the beginning and the end of each element (that will give you your expected output).

Answer (score 0):

```
s="""
set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit

set policy id 1508

exit

set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit

set policy id 1507

set service "TCP-37"

exit
"""
import re
re.findall('(set.*?)^exit',s,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)


['set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR"  "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit\n\nset policy id 1508\n\n', 'set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ"  "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit\n\nset policy id 1507\n\nset service "TCP-37"\n\n']
```

If you want them all on single lines:

```
In [2]: import re   
In [3]: lines  = re.findall('(set.*?)^exit',s, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
In [4]: joined =  [" ".join(x.split()) for x in lines]    
In [5]: joined[0]
Out[5]: 'set policy id 1508 from "TEST" to "OPR" exit "10.2.197.3/32" "ARG-VCENTER-SRV-1" "ANY" permit set policy id 1508'    
In [6]: joined[1]
Out[6]: 'set policy id 1507 from "CMS-SrvFarm" to "DMZ" "CMS-SRV5(10.2.90.14)" "THR-CMS-SRV-0" "TCP-123" permit set policy id 1507 set service "TCP-37"'
```

Comment: your answer is working but it separate each line in an index which is not i wanted. i want the whole words before exit be in the one index of list

Comment: @hgh, they are in separate indexes

Comment: the second example seems to match your expected output, what does not match

Comment: you know, this is my end. there are about 60 lines of this codes. i want separate each part of the code and save them into database like this : policy id : 1508, from : "TEST", to :"OPR", source address : "10.2.197.3/32" and so on. in the first step i separate every line that is mention a specific policy id. then separate information and save them into database. there is some problems even now that i separate policy id codes.